# Idioms and bodyparts: punch your lights out and lights

Tags: etymology, idioms

There is an idiom "*I'll punch your lights out*" which [means](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/punch+lights+out)

> ### punch someone's lights out
>
> Sl. to knock someone out with a fist

There is also "*lights*" which, when used about a body, [mean](http://www.babylon.com/definition/lights%20%28offal%29/)

> ### Lights (Offal)
>
> *noun*
>   the lungs of sheep, pigs, or bullocks, used as food, especially for pets.

I was trying to find whether or not the two were related. The only thing I can think of, which is by no means supported is that if you are to be beaten up then perhaps all the air gets knocked from your lungs?

Comment: Nah, not related. When I punch your lights out, you quite literally can't see light anymore. Simple as that. At the same time, your lungs are still functioning perfectly. If they aren't, you wouldn't say I knocked you out, you'd say I killed you. Also, the part about sheep and pigs should be a *huge* hint.

Comment: @RegDwigнt in fairness, *lights* were once used of human lungs, and remain so in a different colloquial expression. It also wouldn't be that unusual to vulgarly use a term from butchery about human anatomy in the context of a threat of violence.

Comment: @JonHanna Which different colloquial expression (where 'lights' are used for lungs)?

Comment: @Mitch "scare the lights out of". See the end of my answer.

Comment: @JonHanna Oh. Those don't read to me as a usage of lights as innards.

Comment: @Mitch even when combined with liver?

Comment: @JonHanna: I would interpret it as eyes, or the phrasing as a zeugma. Does the OED give examples for the lights as innards?

Comment: @Mitch well lights as innards generally is well-attested, from "Þine þermes..lifre & þine lihte" to "Lungs (commonly known as ‘lites’), whether of cow, sheep or horses, are strongly to be recommended." with "The lungs, or as they are vulgarly termed lights, are eaten as a part of the pluck or fry." as the most recent to use the *light* spelling. Sadly that "are strongly to be recommended" is about what to feed a cat, which shows a decline in dietary range among English-speakers, though the plus is my butcher will sometimes give me free offal as he's glad to see some not go just to dogs.

Comment: @JonHanna - nice...add that to your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two sorts of *lights* one can put out.

One is their "vital spark", that which differs the living from the dead. Hence in the following quotes about putting out someone's lights, it means to kill them:

> But once put out thine, I know not where is that promethian heate, That can thy light returne. — Shakespeare, "Othello".
>
> Quench thou his light, Destruction dark! — Walter Scott, "Lady of Lake"
>
> Put his lights out, to kill — A. J. Pollock, *Underworld Speaks* (a lexicon of criminal slang in 1930s America).

The other is the power of sight, or by extension, in the plural, ones eyes. (The OED describes the use for eyes as "now slang"):

> Lift vp thine eyes..They were not borne to loose their light so soone. — G. Wilkins *Miseries Inforst Mariage*
>
> His ministers with point of piercing sword Put out my light for ever. — R. W. Dixon *Mano*

To punch someone's lights out, is hence to render them (perhaps permanently, but most often temporarily) unable to see by reason of being unconscious or at least greatly stunned.

But the other definition I give above, with the more violent meaning of killing someone, is worth considering too, as a likely influence.

As a slang expression, it's not necessarily one or the other in terms of literal meaning, and figuratively can be much looser again. The threat "I'm going to punch your lights out" can perhaps be interpreted as "I'm going to render a considerable amount of violence upon you, probably with my fists, which will result in a not very well-defined, but certainly considerable, degree of injury". It doesn't need to be clear as to which of the two possible literal meanings it relates to.

(It's possible that Pollock's phrase actually belongs with the second meaning of *lights* rather than the first, and they misinterpreted. Certainly their definition of *bananas* as meaning sexually perverted has little supporting evidence and it could be that they were not as fluent in underworld slang as they thought they were. Note that this was, for a time, the FBI's manual on the topic!)

The definition of *lights* you have found tends not to be used any more of humans. Indeed, the definition you give has it not even used much of food for humans, which seems sad to me (pluck, which is lights mixed up with heart and liver is of course the key ingredient in haggis, and absolutely delicious). The word is derived from the adjective *light* in the sense of not heavy, and was once more often used of people, including the pleonasm "lunges and lightes" from Spenser's *Faerie Queene*.

There is a colloquialism whereby one scares someone so greatly as to remove the lights, and sometimes the liver, out of them:

> It most scared the livers and lights out of me. — Twain, *Adventures Huckleberry Finn*.
>
> You might start by questioning Likhas, scare the lights out of him, and he might tell you. — Pound, translation of Sophocles "Women of Trachis".

Comment: "I'm going to render a considerably amount of violence upon you, probably with my fists, which will result in a not very well-defined, but certainly considerable, degree of injury". I have an urge to threaten somebody using that exact sentence :D

Comment: Yes, such higher-register threats have their own rhetorical advantage over the more common idioms. They can also involve offal, should you for example threaten that "if you do that again, I shall cut out your kidneys and eat them for my Bloomsday breakfast". It just paints a better picture than the general "I will [source of type of injury] your [organ] [optional: through your [other organ]]" pattern.

Comment: I understood *punch your lights out* or *put your daylights out* to mean 'give you two black eyes so serious that you can't see out of them' but have no reference. Sadly those expert in the matter are rarely interested in etymology.

Comment: @TimLymington it fits perfectly with the above, in that it certainly could have been the understanding of people saying and hearing it, much as I already have two difference senses going on simultaneously in what I described.